# Tree minus edge with vertex of degree 1

Tags: graph-theory

I need help proving the following:

Let $T$ be a tree with such that $E(T)=n+1$ and let $v\in V(T)$ a vertex with degree $1$. Let $E\in E(T)$ the edge with one of it's end points equal to $v$. Then $E=vw$ where $w\in V(T)$ and the graph $S$ such that $V(S)=V(T)\setminus\{v\}$ and $E(S)=E(T)\setminus \{vw\}$ is a tree with $\vert V(S)\vert=n$.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that a tree $T$ always has one more vertex than edge:

> $$ \color{purple}{|V(T)| = |E(T)| + 1}. $$

You can prove this by induction on the number of vertices.

**Base case:**

$T$ is a tree with just one vertex and no edges.

**Inductive step:**

Suppose the result holds for all trees with a smaller number of vertices. By selecting a vertex $v$ with degree $1$ and unique edge $vw \in E(T)$ we get a tree $S$ with

$$ |V(S)| = |V(T) \setminus \{v\}| = |V(T)| - 1 $$

and

$$ |E(S)| = |E(T) \setminus \{vw\}| = |E(T)| - 1. $$

Now by induction we know that $|V(S)| = |E(S)| + 1$ so

$$ |V(T)| = |V(S)| + 1 = |E(S)| + 2 = |E(T)| + 1. $$

---

By this formula, if $|E(T)| = n + 1$ then $|V(T)| = |E(T)| + 1 = n + 2$ and

$$ |V(S)| = |V(T) \setminus \{v\}| = |V(T)| - 1 = \color{red}{n + 1}. $$

Comment: I think you should be a little careful here - it's not trivial that removing a vertex and an edge leaves us with a tree. Perhaps some appeal to connectivity/acyclicity in the induction step?

Comment: @platty Thanks for pointing that out. I think that would make a good exercise for 3927 to test their understanding of graphs/trees.